# RDLC : Data precision

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, rdlc

I am using **Visual Studio 2010** and **SQL Server 2008 R2**. I am creating reports using `RDLC`.

My problem is that one of the columns, the values are displayed as rounded integers by default although the column is defined as a `float` at DB view level, `Double` at tableAdapter & report `dataSet` levels. The precision is maintained at all levels only to be lost when displaying the actual report data. I have tried using `FORMAT(value, 2)` and `FORMATNUMBER(value, 2)` to no avail!

How can I maintain precision at 2 decimal points even at report display level? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this code in rdlc Textbox Expression

```
Format(Value,"#0.00")
```

Comment: Thank for the response. This does not solve my problem however. This serves only to give 2 decimal places to already rounded off values. In  other words what should display as 28.44 is only shown as 28.00 and 17.68 as 18.00. It is as if the report object rounds off the Double values before display.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. All along I had the report object plugged into a wrong tableadapter but with similar (column) structure hence the reason the report displayed Integer values instead of Double. Further analysis of data reveal different data sources. Thank you for all the help.